# Get main text only from html documents in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have [url](https://seekingalpha.com/article/4253393-boeing-bear-wakens) (one of the several ones) which I wish to parse and get the main text. I am able to parse it successfully using the following code

```
url = "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4253393-boeing-bear-wakens"

import requests

url = requests.get(url)
html = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()         
text = soup.get_text()
text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

print(text)
```

the text I am getting  is like

*the Boeing Bear Wakens - The Boeing Company (NYSE:BA) | Seeking AlphaMarketplaceSeeking AlphaSUBSCRIBEPortfolioMy PortfoliosAll Portfolios+ Create PortfolioModel PortfoliosPeopleNewsAnalysisSign in / Join NowHelpKnowledge BaseFeedback ForumQuick Picks & Lists | Industrial The Boeing Bear WakensApr.  9, 2019  6:30 AM ET|| About: The Boeing Company (BA)by: Dhierin BechaiDhierin Bechai Aerospace, airlines, Commercial AircraftMarketplaceThe Aerospace ForumSummaryBoeing production temporarily reduced.Very little is known about duration of reduction, but decision to reduce production rate could be sign of long grounding.Production rate decrease adds to downside for Boeing shares.With the Boeing (NYSE:BA) 737 MAX fleet being grounded and deliveries to customers being halted, Boeing is feeling the heat from two sides. While insurers have part of the damages covered,*

it has all the segments like **subscribe, about, time, join etc etc**

I need help on 2 fronts:

1. Is there a generic way to Parse only the main text, No additional element
2. The additional element, can I have it returned in separate, for example if I want to know how much social media impact of the article (like, comment, share on different platforms.

To check the generic nature, kindly try on [url2](https://www.dqindia.com/accenture-helps-del-monte-foods-unlock-innovation-drive-business-growth-cloud/)

Thank you for all the time and help.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out the json format with the script tag and work with that:

```
url = "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4253393-boeing-bear-wakens"

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = requests.get(url)
html = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for script in soup(["script"]):
    if 'window.SA = ' in script.text:

        jsonStr = script.text.split('window.SA = ')[1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';',1)[0]
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

title = jsonObj['pageConfig']['Data']['article']['title']
print (title)
```

There's a lot of info in there. And to get the article:

```
article = soup.find('div', {'itemprop':'articleBody'})
ps = article.find_all('p', {'class':'p p1'})
for para in ps:
    print (para.text)
```

**Output:**

```
The Boeing Bear Wakens
```

Article:

```
With the Boeing (NYSE:BA) 737 MAX fleet being grounded and deliveries to customers being halted, Boeing is feeling the heat from two sides. While insurers have part of the damages covered, it is unlikely that a multi-month grounding will be fully covered. Initially, it seemed that Boeing was looking for a relatively fast fix to minimize disruptions as it was relatively quick with presenting a fix to stakeholders. Based on that quick roll-out, it seemed that Boeing was looking to have the fleet back in the air within 3 months. However, as the fix got delayed and Boeing and the FAA came under international scrutiny, it seems that timeline has slipped significantly as additional improvements are to be made. Initially, I expected that Boeing would be cleared to send the 737 MAX back to service in June/July, signalling a 3-4-month grounding and expected that Boeing's delivery target for the full year would decline by 40 units.



Source: Everett Herald
On the 5th of April, Boeing announced that it would be reducing the production rate for the Boeing 737 temporarily, which is a huge decision:
As we continue to work through these steps, we're adjusting the 737 production system temporarily to accommodate the pause in MAX deliveries, allowing us to prioritize additional resources to focus on software certification and returning the MAX to flight. We have decided to temporarily move from a production rate of 52 airplanes per month to 42 airplanes per month starting in mid-April.
```

You can also obtain the json repsonse of the comments:

```
url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/account/ajax_get_comments?id=4253393&type=Article&commentType=topLiked'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'}


jsonObj_comments = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

As far as a generic approach, that will be difficult as each website has their own structures, formats, use of tags and attribute names, etc. However, I did notice that both sites you provide do use the `<p>` tag for their articles, so I suppose you could pull the text from those tags. However, with a generic approach, you'll get somewhat of generic outputs, meaning you might have excessive text, or missing bits from a an article.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4253393-boeing-bear-wakens"
url2 = "https://www.dqindia.com/accenture-helps-del-monte-foods-unlock-innovation-drive-business-growth-cloud/"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

url = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)
html = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')

for p in paragraphs:
    print (p.text)
```

Comment: Nice approach using json!

Comment: Hi @chitown88 , Really appreciate the answer but I am looking for a generic approach, and that's why I also mentioned a 2nd url in the question. Can we extend this towards a generic algorithm.

Comment: my apologies, I completely missed seeing that second url. I'll take a look at it. However, my initial thought is, no there would not be a generic algorithm that could work for multiple sites....

Comment: .... Unlike tables within websites, which are clearly defined in HTML with `<table>` tags and within those are the rows `<tr>` and the cells in each row `<td>`, written articles could have infinitely many different combinations of tags and class names or ids. Mainly this is because each website is structured differently, and may contain different tag names and attributes. If it is multiple pages within the SAME website, then there is a chance you could use a generic solution as it's likely they structure everything similarly. But again just depends. I'll look at that 2nd ul now though

Comment: Well looking at both sites, you MIGHT be able to do something generic because they do both use the `<p>` tags (which would make sense) for the main bodies of the articles. The only stipulation that I can think with that though is trying to differentiate all the `<p>` tags that do belone to the artcle and that don't. I suppose one could find the `<p>` tags, then get all the '<p>` tags that are siblings. That's all I can think of off the top of my head, and I'll give it shot and see when it comes back with.